# Undefined Offset error although isset() present

Tags: php, arrays, merge, array-merge

As per title I am getting the following error :

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\xampp\htdocs\phpscripts\download-test.php on line 412
```

line 412 is:

```
 if(isset($agent[2])) {
      $agents[$agent[0]][2] += $agent[2];
 } else {
      $agents[$agent[0]][2] = 0;
 } <---- line 412
```

So even though I check if value isset i still manage to get this error. Any one have some ideas ?

Comment: `$agents[$agent[0]][2]` isn't set, you don't check for that.

Comment: I doubt it, that you get the error on the line where your bracket is.

Comment: `$agent[2]` is not `$agent[0][2]`

Comment: you check for agent[2] and you set to agent[0][2] .. check your array structure, and please supply more details from your code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are doing increment & assignment the value of `$agents[$agent[0]][2]` together.

```
$agents[$agent[0]][2] += $agent[2];
```

is same as

```
$agents[$agent[0]][2] = $agents[$agent[0]][2] + $agent[2];
```

Which needs `$agents[$agent[0]][2]` to be set first. The check should be -

```
if(isset($agent[2]) && isset($agents[$agent[0]][2])) {
```

Comment: Yup that was it :) Will accept answer after cool down period. 
@Troll who downvoted - next time you downvote explain why...